# Mirrored object ‚overcuts‘ in object mode only

Tags: object-mode, mirror-modifier

I accidentally did something that makes my mirrored model look like it’s overlapping with its mirror, but only in object mode. When I go into edit mode, the model looks normal and doesn’t over lap. It’s not that it doesn’t clip it appears that the object and it’s mirror are squished into each other. What ever I do, nothing seems to affect this.   [image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Rather than take photos of your monitor post actual screenshots instead, see [How to take a screenshot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org). Photos are harder to read because we have to look past external interferences (like reflections, smudges or Moiré patterns) and guess if we are looking at hardware issues such as a malfunctioning display or connections, a software level issue like driver malfunction or glitch, or actual artifacts or issues with the model itself.